# Hypergeometric Distribution Question

Tags: probability, self-study

I am currently doing a self-study question that gave me the following scenario:

There are 10 marbles in a jar. 7 marbles are red while 3 are blue. John wants to pick 4 marbles out to give his friend. What is the probability that at least 2 marbles are blue?

My attempt to this answer was simple taking (0.3)(0.3)(0.7)(0.7) = 0.0441. However, my answer seems to differ from the answer key which reflected 0.35.

Appreciate any guidance and pointers on what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First hint: You should be using the hypergeometric distribution, which models selection without repalcement. Second hint: Whever you are given a probability problem that asks for "at least" or "at most", don't use direct calculation (i.e., calculate the probability being asked for). Instead, calculate the probability of the opposite (i.e., complement) and subtract from one...it's MUCH easier in many cases.

Comment: Hi Eupraxis1981, I think I am still not getting it right. What I attempted was to take P(X=2) + P(X=3) using hyper-geometic. For P(X=2), (3C2)(7C1)/(10C4) = 0.1. For P(X=3), (3C3)(7C0)/(10C4) = 0.00476. Even when I add them up, they don't add up to 3.5. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Thanks Eupraxis1981! Managed to get the answer after your guidance. =)

Comment: @user1275515 no problem. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

To get the answer I did the following and now it matches up:

Find P(X=2) + P(X=3) using Hyper-geometric Distribution.

P(X=2) = (3C2)(7C2) / (10C4) = 3/10

P(X=3) = (3C3)(7C1) / (10C4) = 1/30

3/10 + 1/30 = 1/3

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer: 1- [C(3/0)xC(7/4)/C(10/4)+C(3/1)xC(7/3)/C(10/4)]
:)

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Some explanation would make this more useful.

Comment: This does not follow the guidelines for answering [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) questions (to give hints and guidance). Further, it lacks any explanation while using an unconventional notation.

Comment: Specifically, unconventional in that putting a "/" between arguments to $C$ means the argument would be likely to be interpreted as a fraction rather than two arguments with a delimiter.